# Image is not uploading (HTML, Java Script)

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js">
</script>

<head>
  Upload Image
</head>

<body>
<p>
  <canvas id="can">
  </canvas>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="finput" 
  onchange="upload()">
</p>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function upload(){
  var canvasinput = document.getElementById("can");
  var fileinput = document.getElementById("finput");
  var image = new SimpleImage(fileinput);
  image.drawTo(canvasinput);
 }
```

I am trying to use a file input to choose an image file, upload it, and display the image on the canvas on webpage. However, It does not display the uploaded image on the canvas. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are there errors on the console?

Comment: The JS file is not available over https

Comment: Actually, it does show an error message on java script: "Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleImage is not defined"

Comment: https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js throws a security error so the browser won't load it.

Comment: Ahh.. it does not show the error message that I mentioned above anymore, for some reason. But it still won't display the image..

Comment: You were right, Quentin. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```js
function upload() {
  var t = event.target;
  var canvasinput = document.getElementById('can');
  var ctx = canvasinput.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(t.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <canvas id="can">
  </canvas>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="finput" 
  onchange="upload()">
</p>
```